# OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 <username>.plist can't be found

Tags: macos, password, user-account

My HDD is encrypted. Accessing Terminal from Recovery Mode -> Utilities. The location `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/` doesn't contain `<user>.plist`.

There is an user account for sure and I can see it on regular boot.

Any ideas what is wrong and alternatively where can I find password hashes for user accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong! In Recovery Mode you can't simply access your common users since the Mac is booted to a special recovery image which doesn't contain your familiar accounts except a *root* user.

To access your common users you first have to unlock and mount the FileVault2 volume and then you can find the hashes at:

```
/Volumes/<Volume_name>/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<user>.plist
```

Comment: How can I find hashes for encrypted disk users without unlocking the disk? Also, I can't access single user mode.

Comment: @user3310984 The hashes are only available in the encrypted volume. AFAIK a derived form of the user passwords are also used in several interleaved keys to unlock the FileVault2 volume but you can't use these keys to recover any user password. To access SU mode you also have to unlock the volume first.

Comment: @user3310984 Please ask another question. An answer would bust the comment section and doesn't fit your question!